# Mysql Hierarchy Path

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I am using [this hierarchy](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) format to build a hierarchy of categories. I am trying to build a search to search the tips table using a full text index. Doing a search works fine, but I would like to get a hierarchy column as from the categories table, where each returned row is separated by a `/`.

**Example:**
Lets say the return looks like this:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| category_name | title       |
+---------------+-------------+
| Computers     | How to jump |
| Video Games   | How to jump |
| Super Mario   | How to jump |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Instead, how can I get the return to look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| category_path                     | title       |
+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| Computers/Video Games/Super Mario | How to jump |
+-----------------------------------+-------------+
```

**Categories Table**

```
mysql> describe categories;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| category_id   | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_name | char(60) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lft           | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rgt           | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

**Tips Table**

```
mysql> describe tips;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tip_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tip         | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

**Here is what I have for a query so far**

```
select * from tips,
categories AS node,
categories AS parent
where match (tips.title, tips.tip) against (? in boolean mode)
AND node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
AND node.category_name = ?
AND parent.lft != 1
ORDER BY node.lft
```

[image: hierarchy]

**Here is my final result:**

```
select title, group_concat(parent.category_name order by parent.lft separator '/') as category_path
from tips, categories as node, categories as parent
where match (tips.title, tips.tip) against ('button' in boolean mode)
and tips.category_id = node.category_id
and node.lft between parent.lft and parent.rgt
and parent.lft != 1
group by title;
```

Comment: An SQLfiddle would help... :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cffda/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer the question you have.  If you have data like this:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| category_name | title       |
+---------------+-------------+
| Computers     | How to jump |
| Video Games   | How to jump |
| Super Mario   | How to jump |
+---------------+-------------+
```

To get it like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| category_path                     | title       |
+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| Computers/Video Games/Super Mario | How to jump |
+-----------------------------------+-------------+
```

You would do:

```
select group_concat(category_name separator '/'), title
from t
group by title;
```

And then you cross your fingers.  This query does not specify the ordering.  If I assume that the original result has an `id` or a `creationdate` or `depth` or *something* that specifies the ordering, then I can do:

```
select group_concat(category_name separator '/' order by id), title
from t
group by title;
```

Comment: Well that works! here is my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cffda/6 Any reason I am getting extra categories? I am getting this: `Cooking/Video Games/Computers/Video Games` and I am hoping for this: `Computers/Video Games`